# Custom Jackson Deserializer For Path Variable In API Controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson, deserialization

I have a Controller where I have the path veriable `resourceId` as type UUID like shown below.

```java
    @GetMapping(value = "{resourceId}")
    public ResponseEntity<MyClass> findOneByResourceId(@PathVariable("resourceId") UUID resourceId) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(myService.findOneByResourceId(resourceId), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Everything works fine exception when Jackson is trying to deserialize an *invalid* UUID if such as "9e3b414a" an exception is thrown. `Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.UUID'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid UUID string: 9e3b414a`

I have already a custom UuidDeserializer class (shown below) which I am using in other areas of my code successfully. I'd like to use this deserializer as well on the pathVariable.

```java
public class UuidDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<UUID> {
    @Override
    public UUID deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException {
        var stringToValidate = jsonParser.getValueAsString().trim();

        if (MyUtils.isStringInvalidUUID(stringToValidate)) {
            throw new MyCustomException("Invalid UUID value")
        }

        return UUID.fromString(stringToValidate);
    }
```

I cannot seem to get Spring to use this custom deserializer though on a path variable. I tried putting the `@JsonDeserialize` on the path variable but it doesn't work. HELP!

```
    @GetMapping(value = "{resourceId}")
    public ResponseEntity<MyClass> findOneByResourceId(@PathVariable("resourceId") 
                                                       @JsonDeserialize(using = UuidDeserializer.class) UUID resourceId) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(myService.findOneByResourceId(resourceId), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom validation annotation to check `UUID`, for example `@UUIDValidation` so first create our custom annotation.

```
@Target({ FIELD, METHOD, PARAMETER, ANNOTATION_TYPE })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = UUIDValidator.class)
@Documented
public @interface UUIDValidation {

    String message() default "Mandatory fields missing";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

Also its custom validator, let's call `UUIDValidator` that should implement `ConstraintValidator` and override the `isValid` method.

```
public class UUIDValidator implements ConstraintValidator<UUIDValidation, UUID> {

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(UUID value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        if (MyUtils.isStringInvalidUUID(value)) {
            throw new MyCustomException("Invalid UUID value");
        }
        try {
            UUID.fromString(value);
            return Boolean.TRUE;
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            return Boolean.FALSE;            
        }
    }
}
```

And we can call our custom validation annotation on the `@PathVariable`

```
@GetMapping(value = "{resourceId}")
public ResponseEntity<MyClass> findOneByResourceId(@PathVariable("resourceId") 
                                                   @UUIDValidation UUID resourceId) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(myService.findOneByResourceId(resourceId), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```